# What is the halacha if a Jew injures another Jew during battle training?

Tags: halacha-theory, army-military-war, injury

I am not aware of any information in the written or oral Torah which discusses what was involved in preparing Jewish army troops for battle, but I assume that soldiers would spar with each other and otherwise engage in physical combat to prepare themselves, similar to the battle preparations of other ancient cultures (e.g. Spartan [Agoge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agoge)). Assuming this is correct, what would the halacha be if one soldier injured another in practice combat? Would this follow the regular laws of damages? Would there be a dispensation because it is in the context of preparing for battle?

I assume similar issues have arisen in modern day Israel, I would accept an answer based on the halachic reasoning used in that context.

Comment: How is this case different from any other case of accidental damages?

Comment: "אדם מועד לעולם" - add. to Josh. There could be a case of voluntary and agreed forgiveness (מחילה), that all the participants apriori sign/agree on mutual non-liability. In Israel IIRC, soldiers can not be sued in a civil court (Let me check it with my son).

Comment: Somewhat related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18721 as well as https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26048 and https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/56335